# Trouble installing rlang in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, rlang

I have just updated my RStudio to 4.1.2 and since then I lost all my packages. I successfully re-installed most of them except for rlang.

I keep receiving this message every time I try to install it. This problem is keeping me away from using other packages because they require rlang. I would really appreicate it if someone can help me out.

```
> install.packages("rlang")

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
      binary source needs_compilation
rlang  1.0.2  1.0.3              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel) Yes
installing the source package ‘rlang’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rlang_1.0.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 740744 bytes (723 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 723 KB

* installing *source* package ‘rlang’ ...
** package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rlang’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/rlang’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rlang’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/01/9wjq8f7n2lb1mbk0q3r408700000gn/T/RtmpEhysP7/downloaded_packages’
> 
> library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘rlang’
>
```

Comment: When asked whether to install from source, answer no instead of yes.

Comment: there is imo opinion an ugly bug hidden somewhere in the rlang from source installation ... at least for 4.0.5 in my case ... very weird